# I reviewed the same edit suggestion twice?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits

A strange thing happened to me in the Suggested Edits review queue:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5182953

As you can see, I seem to have rejected the same edit suggestion twice. I'm guessing this has something to do with my mouse - it seemed to register two clicks instead of one. So apparently, if you send two clicks real fast, you can review the same edit twice?

Also note that this was counted as two reviews, I'm now at 21 instead of the usual 20 (and not due to deleted posts).

Edit: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5235818  . My auto-comment in the Low Quality queue was added twice here. In this case, however, it cost me only one slot.

Comment: Two reject votes on a suggested edit? I have *got* me one of those! Imagine the amount of robo reviews we could head off!

Comment: Yet it didn't appear to affect your ability to reach 20 unique reviews though!

Comment: @Martijn It isn't as much fun as it sounds. You reject the crap and it comes back in front of you for a second time for rejection. Alas! Those who do 23 in a day, experience this thrice :-(

Comment: @Payeli In my case, I saw that edit suggestion only once. It seems that my reject was somehow processed twice.

Comment: So if I wanted my rejections to really stick, I could easily script 3 consecutive mouseclicks? I would assume the same works for approvals then? Sounds like room for abuse, tough with fairly limited impact. Unless this could also happen for other actions on the site, like up/down votes.

Comment: Also relevant (another occurrence of the same thing): http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14185707

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Next build disables double-submission, so hopefully this problem won't present again.

Comment: What, you are fixing this by preventing the client from submitting the form twice? Shouldn't you fix the server-side instead?

Comment: It's on both sides; a post-level lock has been introduced (the same one used during question closure).