# Suggested Edits Review Not Working Correctly

Tags: bug, review-audits

I noticed tonight when reviewing Suggested Edits that I kept seeing the same questions. It kept showing up even though I rejected or approved the edit. [Here is one question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5272491) I kept rejecting but it doesn't show my rejects.

I am unsure if it is my account or are other seeing this problem? I do notice that it doesn't count my reviews. What is interesting is some do work and then I see the "edit test" and I pass that okay.

Is this a bug or an issue with my account?

Am I banned from reviewing edits? (I assume I would see some notice of this?)

*Edit*

I just approved an edit and it worked, next question it won't let me approve the edit. It keeps showing me the same question again and again. It does not count my edit. I assume this is some bug?

Comment: It could just be that that user was very insistent on editing the question. The edit eventually got through. Rolled it back because fixing code in the question isn't what edits are for.

Comment: @user3580294 - I don't think that is the problem. I am seeing this on other questions as well.

Comment: Then I'm not too sure what's going on. Sorry... On a side note, I'm constantly getting notifs for the same rep change when I refresh the page, so maybe there's some server thing that isn't saving. No clue.

Comment: [It happens sometimes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262000/i-reviewed-the-same-edit-suggestion-twice?rq=1). On a bad day, you review the same thing multiple times.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion: The question you link doesn't look like the same problem. I just saw the same thing that this OP is describing. I clicked Approve about 4 times, but the same review would just display again, without my vote being registered. I had to click Skip to get beyond the review.