# Why was I able to vote on the same answer twice in the Low Quality Post queue?

Tags: bug

I see a similar [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262000/i-reviewed-the-same-edit-suggestion-twice) involving Suggested Edits.  My issue involves the Low Quality queue.

I was twice given the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747449/how-to-disable-zoom-in-navigator) question to review.  Here is what happened:

I first approved it (too quickly I admit).  I then returned to the answer and edited it for a few items (spelling, capitalization, grammatical correctness).  Then later on in reviewing I was given the same answer back (with my edits in place).  This time I did (I think correctly) accept this as a legitimate answer.

So why did I get to review the same answer twice?  Was it because I had edited it in between reviews?  In any case, I don't think this is desirable behavior for the queue.

---

**Reviews**

- [1st review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5333219)
- [2nd review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5333256)

So they are both low quality queue reviews.

Comment: can you link to each of the review pages you acted on?  Did you look at the post in two different queues?

Comment: Perhaps related to the change on the review page? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266000/1007939

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've seen a few questions in the review queue more than once in the last few weeks as well; but trying to find them at only 20/page is too painful.  Otherwise I'd've reported it myself.

Comment: Does an edit to a LQP automatically put it back in the LQ review queue?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is *desirable behavior*.

Note that we are trying to be constructive here, so the low-quality queue is meant to be a place where you first try to improve the post if possible, e.g.:

- putting inline content into a link-only answer if possible
- Fix grammar issues like you have greatly done
- Fix code formatting issues
- Fix visibility issues due to the wrong usage of the markup
- etc.

... and only then if it really cannot salvage, you recommend the deletion or cast a delete vote on it if you have enough reputation for that privilege.

When you edit an answer that is flagged as low-quality for instance, the flag will be marked as helpful.

It is likely the reason that you edited this answer, which is well done and I appreciate it, and then someone else flagged it again which put it back into the low-quality queue.

Now, it is desirable that we do not lock out previous reviewers for a different revision of an answer. Since it is a different revision, it deserves another look even from a person who reviewed any previous revision of it.

This is why people need to be careful in general when editing such posts because some people - not you - like editing everything they can(not), and that dismisses the procedure for the deletion in worse cases. I have seen it happening, and I could not get an answer flagged again easily without moderator intervention.

Despite the comment above, I believe that [this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266000/review-page-does-not-work-as-before) is likely not the culprit.